# How to create custom server alias in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My enterprise uses a company-wide management to all SQL Server instances, which causes all servers are named with similar name but hard to memorize their function, like

- `server_11001_sqlserver.company.com` for development
- `server_11002_sqlserver.company.com` for production
- `server_11003_sqlserver.company.com` for another team production
- `server_11015_sqlserver.company.com` for my team backup etc.

I need some way to clearly distinguish them such like building custom alias, which might be only visible to myself, in SSMS, to make development work easier. However, creating alias via configuration manager is not allowed for various reasons.

Are there any alternative ways?

Comment: Can you elevate and edit your hosts file? eg `notepad c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Answer (score 0):

create or delete a server alias in SQL Server by using SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Expand SQL Server Native Client Configuration in SQL Server Configuration Manager, click Aliases, and then choose New Alias from the context menu.

Type the alias name in the Alias Name box. Client apps connect using this name.

Enter a server's name or IP address in the Server box. A named instance's instance name should be appended.

Select the protocol that this alias uses in the Protocol box. The Port No, Pipe Name, or Connection String title of the optional attributes box changes when a protocol is chosen.

Programmers who build their own connection strings may find the connection strings provided in the SQL Server Configuration Manager Help to be helpful. Press F1 to retrieve this data in the New Alias dialog box.